# C++ thread-safe increment with modulo without mutex using std::atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I need a thread-safe pool of Buffer-objects used in a round-robin fashion. I normally would just put a mutex in there to make the increment and modulo thread safe, but is it possible to write it using std::atomic? Here's a sample interface. If it makes things easier the total number of buffers can be a power of two. The next buffer index is never accessed outside of the class.

```
class Buffer;

class BufferManager
{
public:

    BufferManager( size_t totalBuffers = 8 ) : mNextBufferIndex( 0 ), mTotalBuffers( totalBuffers )
    {
        mBuffers = new Buffer*[mTotalBuffers];
    }

    Buffer* GetNextBuffer()
    {
        // How to make this operation atomic?
        size_t index = mNextBufferIndex; 

        mNextBufferIndex = ( mNextBufferIndex + 1 ) % mTotalBuffers;

        return mBuffers[index];
    }

private:
    Buffer**            mBuffers;
    size_t              mNextBufferIndex;
    size_t              mTotalBuffers;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modulo can be safely used after choosing

```
std::atomic<size_t> mNextBufferIndex;

    Buffer* GetNextBuffer()
    {
       // How to make this operation atomic?
       size_t index = mNextBufferIndex ++; 

       size_t id = index % mTotalBuffers;

       // If size could wrap, then re-write the modulo value.
       // oldValue keeps getting re-read.  
       // modulo occurs when nothing else updates it.
       size_t oldValue =mNextBufferIndex;
       size_t newValue = oldValue % mTotalBuffers;
       while (!m_mNextBufferIndex.compare_exchange_weak( oldValue, newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed ) )
            newValue = oldValue % mTotalBuffers; 
       return mBuffers[id ];
    }
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense - the next buffer index doesn't actually *need* need modulo, only incremented with thread safety. And as long as the max value of the type of mNextBufferIndex is greater than or equal to mTotalBuffers (as is here) this just works. Thanks.

Comment: OP might be OK with that, but it is a different thing from doing the whole operation atomically or inside mutex.

Comment: @SergeyA I wasn't clear, you are right - I think this is the right answer.

Comment: Shouldn't be `size_t index = mNextBufferIndex.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);`?

Comment: I am not sure - I will have to read up on the function you suggest @Nimrod

Comment: @mksteve My bad and let it go.

Answer (score 2):

You could just declare the `mNextBufferIndex` an `std::atomic_ullong` and then use

```
return mBuffers[(mNextBufferIndex++) % mTotalBuffers];
```

The increment will be atomic and you compute the modulo just before returning.

Using a very large unsigned will avoid problems that would occur when the counter wraps.

Comment: Right of course - I can use an unsigned but then I have no control over the range. it's a great solution when it works, but here I need the number of buffers to be user-defined.

Comment: @Steven: you compute the modulo before using the index!

Comment: Right - you and mksteve both gave me the same thing - I see it now.

Comment: This only works if `mTotalBuffers` is a power of 2. If not, an overflow will change the value of the modulo.

Comment: @Vortico: that's why I was using an `unsigned long long` as the counter,  the problem may arise after 18446744073709551616 buffer switches.

Comment: True, it's just a theoretical "incorrectness" if your architecture supports 64-bit atomics. But a practical incorrectness for 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible when you have two inputs. All you can do with atomic is either use CPU-supported atomic instructions (and I am yet to hear of the chip which can do increment plus modulo as an operation), or you can do calculation first and than set the value provided the input didn't change - but your function does have two inputs, so this will not work either.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's hardware assisted interlocked operations for this. One such operation is increment. You don't need to make it more complicated since the modulo operation can act independently from the increment operation.

`std::atomic` does overload the `operator++` and I would think that it has the atomic guarantee.

```
Buffer* GetNextBuffer()
{
   // Once this inc operation has run the return value
   // is unique and local to this thread the modulo operation
   // does not factor into the consistency model 
   auto n = mNextBufferIndex++; 
   auto pool_index = n % mTotalBuffers;
   return mBuffers[pool_index];
}
```

If you wanted to do it with the modulo or any other complex arithmetic you use a compare and exchange version.

The idea between compare and exchange or compare and swap is that you do your computation and when you want to write the value back to the memory location (shared or otherwise) it will only succeed if no one else did not modify the value in the meantime (if they do you just retry the operation, busy-wait). This requires only a predictable numbering scheme which is often very possible to do.

```
Buffer* GetNextBuffer()
{
   // Let's assume that we wanted to do this
   auto n = (mNextBufferIndex % mTotalBuffers) ++; 
   mNextBufferIndex = n;
   return mBuffers[n];
}
```

Assuming `mNextBufferIndex` is an `std::atomic`.

```
Buffer* GetNextBuffer()
{
   // Let's assume that we wanted to do this
   auto n = (mNextBufferIndex % mTotalBuffers)++;
   // This will now either succeed or not in the presence of concurrency
   while (!std::compare_exchange_weak(mNextBufferIndex, n)) {
     n = (mNextBufferIndex % mTotalBuffers)++;
   }
   return mBuffers[n];
}
```

You may think that this is more akin to optimistic concurrency control but if you limit your self to a definition of what is atomic that is too narrow you won't get anything done.

Putting aside that what I'm computing here is complete nonsense is shows how powerful the the `compare_exchange` operation is and how to use it to make any arithmetic atomic. The problem is really when you have multiple computations that depend on each other. You need to code in a lot of recovery routines when this is the case.

Though, interlocked operations by themselves are not free and evict cache lines in the processor.

For reference I can recommend Mike Acton's [paper slides](https://macton.smugmug.com/Other/2008-06-18-by-Eye-Fi/n-3Q2Vv/i-DVDVwSV) about the **increment problem**.

Comment: Disagree. There are two variable inputs to the operation, so it can not be made true atomic (so that it would be indistinguishable from the mutex).

Comment: @SergeyA that depends on what you mean by atomic. For me, the end result is that either the whole operation happens or it does not. The whole purpose of this operation is just to maintain consistency. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I mean, that it takes into account two operands. In your case, you first calculate n as a product of mNextBufferIndex and mTotalBuffers. Then you use only one of them - mNextBufferIndex - as an argument of CaS. If the second did change in process, your CaS will not detect it, and the value would be different. Basically, you will end up using new value for one variable and old value for another. Semanically it's different from lock, which would guarantee both values are old.

Comment: I'm simply assuming that `mTotalBuffers` is constant

Comment: Which might be true for all I know - but original question does not state that. This is why my (downvoted for reasons unclear to me) answer is that you can't do that.

Comment: @SergeyA Did not down vote but I think it's because you start off with "*It is not possible...*". See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168/58961 Personally, I think your answer is just pedantic. Practically this is all very doable whether we agree on the same definition of atomicity or not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability Again, did not down vote but I think this is kinda why someone did...